# How do I integrate Dialogflow with new Google sites?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-sites-2016

It looks like new Google sites does not support scripting. Is there any other way I can integrate Dialogflow with Google sites besides using embed code? I'd like a chat widget to pop up on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Only Classic Sites (Previous version) supported Apps Script where you might have been able to add that.

New Sites, the closest thing that can be added to it are HTML and JavaScript as suggested by their official documentation.

**Reference**

- https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-html-css-or-javascript-code-to-your-site